# How can I locate data present in os running on virtual machine on my system's hard disk?

Tags: windows, windows-7, vmware

I am running backtrack on vmware,while running windows 7 as base operating system.Can I find the location of data present in backtrack OS through my Windows 7 OS.If yes,How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire virtual hard disk from a virtual machine is generally stored inside a single file on the host OS' file system. This is generally of a proprietary format and requires third party software to mount from the host OS - and this must be done while the VM is not running. Additionally, this is only possible if the target partition on the VM is a filesystem supported by the host OS. Backtrack being a Linux, this is rather unlikely.

Short answer, probably no.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's Virtual PC (Or at least `XPMODE`'s version of VPC) has the option of making part of the Host's file system available to the VPC under Integration Features.
[image: Integration Features]
<sub>(source: [mediafire.com](http://www.mediafire.com/conv/e51fd5fe873d312d319ae406c4cfb8997e98aac65f570a6e5ad8b7e7af0498ee6g.jpg))</sub>

I would imagine that that would also be possible with vmware, though the little bit of searching I did only turned up a method of using an entire physical disk and / or partition of the hosts disk.

I found that here:
http://pubs.vmware.com/server1/vm/disks_add_raw_gsx.html#1039236

If all else fails, you should be able to share files and folders over the network like this:

```
\\.host\Shared Folders\Test files
```

There is more information about that here:
http://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/running_sharefold_ws.html

Comment: OP wants to access the VM hard drive from the host OS, not the host's hard drive from inside the VM.

Comment: @tomfanning - If he puts the data he wants to access on the hosts drive, whats the difference?